# How to find $\displaystyle \int_2^4\left( \log_x2-\frac{\log_x^22}{\ln 2}\right)dx$?

Tags: integration

> How to find $\displaystyle \int_2^4\left( \log_x2-\frac{\log_x^22}{\ln 2}\right)dx$?

My try:
Let $x=2^t,dx=2^tdt$
$$I=\int_1^2 \left(\frac1t-\frac1{t^2\ln 2}\right)2^tdt=\int_1^2 \left(\frac1t-\frac1{t^2\ln 2}\right)e^{t\ln 2}dt=?$$
Any Help?

Comment: Also, you lost a constant factor in your substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If I may suggest, rewrite first $$ \log_x2-\frac{\log_x^22}{\ln 2}=\frac{\log (2)}{\log (x)}-\frac{\log (2)}{\log ^2(x)}$$ So, now using $x=e^t$, $$\displaystyle \int\left( \log_x2-\frac{\log_x^22}{\ln 2}\right)dx= \int\left( \frac{\log (2)}{\log (x)}-\frac{\log (2)}{\log ^2(x)}\right)dx=\log(2)\int \Big(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^2}\Big)e^t dt$$ where you recognize something nice, I am sure.

I am sure that you can take from here.